# How to bring a new window open in front of Main Window in WPF after switching to any other application in MVVM architecture?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

How can I resolve the following problem?

1. Run a WPF app, MainWindow is opened in front
2. New window is shown behind after opening any other application Main window is also disabled then have to press the ALT+Tab to take the new window and close it.

   ```
   NewWindow newWindow = new NewWindow ();
   newWindow.ShowDialog();
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it correct when I gave like this:

```
  NewWindow newWindow = new NewWindow ();
  newWindow.Owner= Application.Current.MainWindow;
  newWindow.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 3):

Set the `Owner` for your second window like this:

```
NewWindow newWindow = new NewWindow();
newWindow.Owner = this;
newWindow.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I have thought, that you call ShowDialog() from Application.Current.MainWindow.