# WPF window hides behind the main app window. Trying to bring it to front

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a 3rd part application which calls a simple WPF window which has a button which starts another WPF window.

`MainApp` -> `Window1` -> `Window2`

The way the code is setup `Window1` should be closed after starting `Window2` which is working all well and good, but `Window2` goes "behind" the `MainApp` window and hence is not visible. That is what I am trying to fix

Things that I have tried:

`Window.TopMost`: This is fine but the problem is that the window stays on top of all the windows when I <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

`Activate()` \ `Focus()`: These did not work

I also tried sending an <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> key stroke which seemed to fix the issue except that `Window1` did not close at all.

I even tried combinations of `Activate()` \ `Focus()` \ `TopMost` from different SO posts but nothing seemed to work.

Code:

```
void btn_click()    // Window1
{
    Myclass.ShowMyDialog();
    res = DialogResult...
    Close();
}

// Myclass
public static void ShowMyDialog()
{
    s_window2 = new Window2();
    s.window2.Closed += OnClosed;
    s_window2.Show()
}
```

Comment: Try window.BringIntoView();

Comment: Tried that as well... did not work.

Comment: Is one of the windows called by the `ShowDialog()` method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bring a new window open in front of Main Window in WPF after switching to any other application in MVVM architecture?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42997834/how-to-bring-a-new-window-open-in-front-of-main-window-in-wpf-after-switching-to)

Comment: @Rekshino I have tried those solutions as well, but did not help

Answer (score 3):

Owner property should do the trick. Try below code:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
        this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;                        
    }

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window1 win1 = new Window1();    //In your case, object of window2            
        win1.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
        win1.Show();
    }
```

Comment: You are showing window2 once window1 is closed, right?

Comment: Can you please show your code where you are calling .Show() on Window2?

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. this is how I fixed the issue. The problem was that when I was starting the main app (3rd party) and then Window 1 was loaded, it was Modal and hence stopped the 3rd party from loading (document). I was opening my Window 2 from Window 1, and then closing Window 1. Since they are in the same thread, Window1 returned control to the main application (it came to front and it continued loading) and hence Window2 was "hiding".
As a solution, I now start the Window 2 in a different thread, and that seems to fix the issue.